# PowerMock where static methods call static methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, static-methods, powermock

A coworker was trying to write a test over two static methods where one static method called the other.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ ProcessUtil.class, ImageConverter.class })
public class ImageConverterTest {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ImageConverterTest.class.getName());

    @Test
    public void getImageMagicVersion() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProcessUtil.class);

        PowerMockito.when(
                ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult(Matchers.eq(new String[] { "/usr/bin/convert", "--version" })))
                .thenReturn(OLD_IMAGE_MAGIC);

        String version = ImageConverter.getImageMagicVersion();

        verifyStatic();

        ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult(new String[] { "/usr/bin/convert", "--version" });

        log.info("Image magic version: " + version);
        assertEquals(version, OLD_IMAGE_MAGIC);
    }
}
```

`OLD_IMAGE_MAGIC` is a static final string.

When we look at `ImageConverter.getImageMagicVersion` all that it does is build the string array and pass it into `ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult`.  If `ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult` is not mocked and runs I expect an exception.

Neither `ProcessUtil` nor `ImageConverter` are final, they are both standard classes with all static methods on them.

The problem we are seeing is that the version being returned is `null`, yet I can also verify the call on the static method as being done and correct.  When I call `ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult` inside of the test, it returns the correct value.

The version of PowerMock being used is 1.5.4 and we are using it in conjunction with Mockito (though such isn't relevant in this code sample) and JUnit 4.11.  Any ideas about what we might be doing wrong that would lead to this sort of outcome?

Comment: why are you mocking ´ImageConverter´ if it is the class you want to test? Furthermore, you prepare it for mocking but you never mock it

Comment: They aren't mocking it, it is being prepared for test only (probably as part of trying to get this to work), but removing that does not impact outcome.

Comment: Two possible things can happen here. 1: the class ´ProcessUtil´ is final and thus not mockable. 2: the method ´ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult´ is not being called with those exact attributes

Comment: ProcessUtil is not final, and the verify succeeds. If I distort the verify arguments, it fails and gives the expected error message. Similarly, matching against `any(String[].class)` also succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We determined the problem.

PowerMock was treating the following as different:

```
ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult(String [] values)
```

and

```
ProcessUtil.execAndReturnResult(String... values)
```

The problem was that we weren't using a varArg matcher, but rather a straight array match. Switching to a vararg matcher (or switching to different data type) fixed the problem.